# Cloud armor request.path.startswith lets traffic bypass random

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

In Google Cloud Armor I have multiple rules (+50). Below is the one with lowest priority number. It is based on bad_path URI example in [Cloud Armor documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_for_a_request_uri_that_matches_a_regular_expression)

```
request.path.startsWith('/api/foo')
Deny 403
Priority: 1
Activated 1st November
```

In **Google cloud logging**, I *believe* the rule can be bypassed:

```
resource.type:(http_load_balancer) AND
jsonPayload.enforcedSecurityPolicy.name:(rules) AND
log_name="projects/foo_bar/logs/requests" AND
httpRequest.requestUrl="https://foo.example.io/api/foo" AND
```

The request pattern is:

```
https://foo.example.io/api/foo
```

The data below are sampled from 2 minutes:

| Outcome | statusDetails | http status | Priority | requestMethod | RequestSize | timestamp | receiveTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Deny | denied_by_security_policy | 403 | 1 | POST | 1188 | 12:49:48.746858Z | 12:50:24 |
| Deny | denied_by_security_policy | 403 | 1 | POST | 1191 | 12:49:48.297242Z | 12:50:02 |
| Allow | response_sent_by_backend | 200 | 60000 | POST | 1189 | 12:49:48.924442Z | 12:50:36 |
| Deny | denied_by_security_policy | 403 | 1 | POST | 1189 | 12:49:48.924468Z | 12:50:29 |
| Deny | denied_by_security_policy | 403 | 1 | POST | 1184 | 12:49:48.990177Z | 12:49:50 |

The below fields are same for all requests:

```
backend_service_name: Same for all above
forwarding_rule_name: Sane for all above
url_map_name: Same for all above
```

Example of 403 httpRequest

```
httpRequest: {
 latency: "0.1"
 remoteIp: "x.x.x.x"
 requestMethod: "POST"
 Requestsize: "1200"
 requestUrl: https://foo.example.io/api/foo
 responsesize: "315"
 status: 403
 userAgent: "XYZ"
}
```

Example of 200 httpRequest

```
httpRequest: {
 latency: "0.5"
 remoteIp: "x.x.x.x"
 requestMethod: "POST"
 Requestsize: "1202"
 requestUrl: https://foo.example.io/api/foo
 responsesize: "3150"
 serverIp: "x.x.x"
 status: 200
 userAgent: "XYZ"
}
```

**In Google cloud logging (audit logs)**

```
cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
resource.type="network_security_policy"
```

There are 3 cloud armor updates, but they are all a few hours after the timestamp above.

| Rule | ValidateOnly | Resource | timestamp | receiveTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2500 | true | network_security_policy | 14:02:03 | 14:02:04 |
| 2500 | N_A | network_security_policy | 14:02:05 | 14:02:06 |
| N_A | N_A | network_security_policy | 14:02:11 | 14:02:12 |

What more steps can I take to understand why the rule is bypassed sometimes? The above example is not an isolated incident.

I don't think the ["Cloud Armor POST body inspection limitation"](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#post-body) is relevant here.

Comment: I do not see any requests bypassed in your post.

Comment: Isn't response_sent_by_backend, as status detailed indicating that the request were bypassing the cloud armor? Those requests gets HTTP response 200 instead of 402. I will update the table with http status

Comment: That is a response, not a request. If Cloud Armor allows an HTTP request, the response is automatically allowed. Cloud Armor Security Policies operating on HTTP (Layer 7) incoming (request) traffic.

Comment: Sorry for mixing the terminology. The question is updated with two httpRequest JSON that are fetched from the log. The x values are changed. The requestUrl have same value in original json. How can I verify if the request: https://foo.example.io/api/foo bypassed my cloud armor rule? Since all egress traffic is allowed.

Comment: Are the JSON MIME types the same? You might want to try and inform Cloud Armor the MIME type you are using: https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning#post-parsing . Are these JSON requests for GraphQL service? If so, you can also enable the special parser for GraphQL: gcloud compute security-policies update POLICY_NAME \
    --json-parsing STANDARD_WITH_GRAPHQL